# send keys to the right pane in Tmux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

Currently I hard coded the pane of which to send the keys to, I wonder how can I send the command to the right pane of the pane I'm currently focused on?

Current:

```
bind b send-keys -t 2 'make' Enter
```

Would like to have:

```
bind b send-keys -t toTheRightPane 'make' Enter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer from [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=v1NuzPpXFfM)

```
bind b send-keys -t right 'make' Enter
```

Comment: Other options include {down-of}, {bottom-left}, {top}, {up-of}, and more. e.g. `bind b send-keys -t {down-of} 'make' Enter`. That would send keys to the pane "down-of" (i.e. below) the currently active pane.

Answer (score 2):

More generic: repeat the last command in the last active pane - works with any build tool and any pane setup.

```
bind C-b send-keys -t ! C-p C-j
```